# I don't understand how to integrate my Model in my Viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am building a small personal project using Wpf, CaliburnMicro and using the mvvm pattern.
The application is a touch screen that let the user see the room temperature and let him select the Order he wants on a Climatizer (Ventilation, Cold, Hot, Off) and will show if that Order has been "confirmed" from the climatizer.(Feedback Order). Data from the Climatizer come from Serial communication.
I have a ClimControlModel class that encapsulate data like RoomTemperature, Order and FeedBack Order.

I have simplified the ClimControl class so the code doesn't take too many lines here on StackOverflow, and i am only trying to display RoomTemperature in the View.

ClimControlModel.cs:

```
namespace WpfMetroCaliburn.Models
{
    public enum OrderValue
    {
        OFF,
        VENT1,
        VENT2,
        VENT3,
        COLD,
        HOT,
        OFFLINE
    }
    public class ClimControlModel
    {
        public float RoomTemperature { get; set; } = 99F; // fake value for testing
        public OrderValue Order { get; set; }
        public OrderValue FeedbackOrder { get; set; }


        public ClimControlModel()
        {
           // will change val of RoomTemperature and FeedcackOrder every 5 seconds
            ChangePropretiesPeriodically();
        }

        // this will simulate updating datas from Serial
        public void ChangePropretiesPeriodically()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnPropretiesChangeTimerEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 5000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        // Assigning random values to RoomTemperature and Feedback Order for testing purposes
        private void OnPropretiesChangeTimerEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(OrderValue));
            Random random = new Random();
            FeedbackOrder = (OrderValue)values.GetValue(random.Next(values.Length));

            Random rnd = new Random();
            RoomTemperature = rnd.Next(20, 33);
            Console.WriteLine($"FakeClimControlModel: RoomTemperature is now: {RoomTemperature}");
        }
    }
}
```

ShellViewModel :

```
namespace WpfMetroCaliburn.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Screen
    {

        private ClimControlModel _clim;

        public ClimControlModel Clim
        {
            get { return _clim; }
            set {
                _clim = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Clim);
            }
        }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            Clim = new ClimControlModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
Window x:Class="WpfMetroCaliburn.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfMetroCaliburn.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Clim_RoomTemperature" FontSize="25"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I understand it doesn't work because the instance of ClimControlModel doesn't actually trigger NotifyOfPropertyChange as the object itself doesn't change, it's the values of the object's properties that change.
However what would be the "best practice" in that case, as if i create a RoomTemperature, Order, Feedback Order properties in the ViewModel, how can i have their values changed automatically in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the properties of the model are changing, the only way for the view to notice the change is for the model to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` when a property changes.

In other words, for each of your properties in your model, change this style:

```
public float RoomTemperature { get; set; }
```

to

```
private float roomTemperature;
public float RoomTemperature 
{ 
    get => this.roomTemperature;
    set
    {
        this.roomTemperature=value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
    } 
}
```

If instead you added similar properties in the ViewModel, they wouldn't be notified when the model changes.

Another way to do it would be for the ViewModel to subscribe to the Timer event, and then raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` events.

Comment: It works thank you! I'm sorry i don't have enough point to upvote your answer.